# Object isn't inserted into Room database

Tags: android, database, object, android-room

I have an Android app which uses Room Database. I have several tables and all of them works just fine, except one - the User object(table). I'm using the same approach for all of the object(tables), but still, data isn't inserted into this exact one. The table is still empty. Even though other tables are populated just fine. Bellow is my code.

In the Fragment, if the user presses the button, the fabClickHandler method is called. The method checks if there is already a user in DB created. If it is, it returns his API key and uses for a request. If it is not present, it asks for an input of API key. Then it should store it to DB, but it doesn't. It asks again next time and I have checked the table and it is indeed empty.

If populated the table with the User object manually, everything works just fine.

**User.java:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int uid;
    private String name;
    private String apikey;

    public User(int uid, String name, String apikey) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.apikey = apikey;
    }

    @Ignore
    public User(String name, String apikey) {
        this.name = name;
        this.apikey = apikey;
    }

    @Ignore
    public User() {
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getApikey() {
        return apikey;
    }

    public void setApikey(String apikey) {
        this.apikey = apikey;
    }
}
```

**UserDao.java:**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public void insertUser(User user);
```

Fragment:

```
public void fabClickHandler() {
        database = AppDatabase.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
        userDao = database.userDao();
        String keyFromDB = "NOTHING_FETCHED";
        try {
            keyFromDB = checkDBForUserAPIKey()[0];
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG_INFO, "First keyFromDB: " + keyFromDB);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!keyFromDB.equals("GOT_NULL") && !keyFromDB.equals("NOTHING_FETCHED") && !keyFromDB.equals("NOTHING_FOUND")) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG_INFO, "Second keyFromDB: " + keyFromDB);
            resourcesController.getFactoriesList(keyFromDB, factoriesAdapter);
        } else {
            pricesController.getMarketPricesAvgsList(pricesAdapter);
            final EditText input = new EditText(activity);
            final String[] user_apikey = {"NONE_ENTERED"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_apikey_enter_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_apikey_enter_title).setView(input);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_apikey_enter_positive_button, (dialog, which) -> {
                user_apikey[0] = input.getText().toString();
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG_INFO, "Third keyFromDB: " + user_apikey[0]);
                new Thread(() -> {
                    userDao.insertUser(new User(1, "Main", user_apikey[0]));
                });
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Syncing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resourcesController.getFactoriesList(user_apikey[0], factoriesAdapter);
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_apikey_enter_negative_button, (dialog, which) -> {
                user_apikey[0] = "DIALOG_CANCELED";
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG_ERROR, "API key dialog canceled");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Dialog canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
            AlertDialog apikey_dialog = builder.create();
            apikey_dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

when I print the "Third keyFromDB: " (see in the code), the API key is there, but then the object is not inserted into a table.

I don't know what else I should do. I have used this same DB approach previously and never had a problem.

Comment: **Edit:** I still haven't found a solution to this problem, but as a workaround, I'm now saving the user's API key to SharedPreferences instead and this works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using these lines in your User Entity?

```
@Ignore
public User(String name, String apikey) {
    this.name = name;
    this.apikey = apikey;
}

@Ignore
public User() {
}
```

`@Ignore` ignores the marked element from Room's processing logic.

This annotation can be used in multiple places where Room processor runs. For instance, you can add it to a field of an Entity and Room will not persist that field.

Remove it from your User entity, and it will works.

For reference [Defining data using Room entities](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)

**UPDATE:**

Is this the only line where you inserting a new user? `userDao.insertUser(new User(1, "Main", user_apikey[0]));`

If yes, then it will return only one user, because all the time you are inserting `1` as `uid` and it will replace the previous user as the `uid` is the primary key.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Removing the annotations didn't solve the problem. In fact, I haven't had them there before, but I added them as one of the attempts to solve it. If you have multiple constructors defines, Room complains during compilation with 
`There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor. You can use the @Ignore annotation to eliminate unwanted constructors.`
I have tried to Ignore all combinations to try to force Room to use every single one of them and nothing helped.

Comment: **Reply to update:** Yes, that's my intention. I only want this one user to be added in this step and always be replaced if the line called again. The thing is that if the User is created in the database, it should skip creating this user and only use his API key from DB. I have a separated method which checks this. Anyway, the point is that it doesn't even create the one User.

Comment: **Edit:** I still haven't found a solution to this problem, but as a workaround, I'm now saving the user's API key to SharedPreferences instead and this works just fine.